# Jquery if/else remove class on dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello im trying to append and remove a css class depending on what value is in the div

if the value is equal to custom now i add a class that removes the :after appended to my text.

I want to reapply the class if it otherwise.

```
setInterval(function() {
  $('.monthappend').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('$0', 'CUSTOM'));

    if ($(this).text() == 'CUSTOM') {
      $('.monthappend').addClass('without-after-element');
    } else {
      $('.monthappend').removeClass('without-after-element');
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

this else statement didnt work... i tried adding another interval check after this one

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {
  $('.monthappend').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() != 'CUSTOM') {
      $('.monthappend').removeClass('without-after-element');
    }
  });
}, 2000);
</script>
```

but this just caused the appended text to appear and reappear in a loop.

Please help!

site im working this code on
https://staging-homecarepulse.kinsta.cloud/pricing-calc-2/

Comment: You probably want `$(this).removeClass("without-after-element")` unless you want to remove the class from all the `.monthappend` elements based on the text value of one

Comment: post as a answer so i can upvote you @phil

Comment: this worked splendidly